# How and where are the methods defined within the ViewController.m file in my XCode project called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, xcode, uicollectionview

Started learning Objective-C and XCode yesterday. Coming from a Rails background, I expect class methods like the ones defined in the ViewController.m file to be called at some point. I assume this is also the case in Objective-C, but I can't find where these methods are used.

To be more specific: I am working with a Collection View. I have the following method that defines the amount of sections in my view.

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView{
    return 1; 
}
```

Firstly, I cannot find out where the method is called. How does numberOfSectionsInCollectionView get its UICollectionView argument?

Put another way - if this were Ruby and I defined the method like so:

```
Class ViewController
   def numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView)
       return 1
   end
end
```

I would expect a view controller object (viewController = ViewController.new) to call the method somewhere (viewController.numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(argument)). I'm not seeing the objective-c equivalent here. Can anyone help me understand this?

As an aside, why would you pass in an argument to a method that's never used?

Comment: This method is part of the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol. It is called by the UiCollectionView when it needs to know how many sections it has. You may have more than one UICollectionView being served by the same data source, so it may need to know which UICollectionView it is responding to. The delegation pattern is widely used in iOS - read up on it.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Can you point me to where (as in what file) UICollectionView calls the method?

Comment: Read the documentation for UICollectionView and its `datasource` property - this will lead you to the documentation for `UICollectionViewDataSource`. If you look at the definition of your class you will see that it implements this protocol. You won't see an explicit call to this method because it is in the source code for UICollectionView, which you don't have.

Comment: That last sentence is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you. I have been scanning the docs backwards and forwards and looking through all my files trying to understand where these methods were being called. 

It seems odd to me that the calls for these methods are behind the scenes., but I suppose it's something I'll have to get used to. Thanks again.

Comment: It is part of any object oriented system - the idea that one object can pass messages to another through interface definitions without either object needing to anything specific about the other.